# Referencing a value from the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to write query in `Sql Server 2014` for the following condition:
I need to add the first row `CurrentKM` value in second row `LastKM` column like that it has to go.

```
VNo  CurrKM   LastKM
1    15000    0
2    16000    15000
3    17000    16000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using LAG:

```
Select VNo,CurrKM, LAG(CurrKM,1,0) over (order by VNo asc) LastKM
From Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id int,currkm int)
insert into @t (id,currkm)values (1,15000),(2,16000),(3,17000)
;with cte as(
select distinct id,currkm,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( order by id desc,currkm desc)R from @t)
select c.id,c.currkm,cc.currkm from cte c
LEFT JOIN cte cc
on cc.R - 1 = c.R
ORDER BY c.id
```